# How to set working directory (error "object" missing)

Tags: r, directory, rstudio

I am trying to set the working directory, but I receive an error that says that the active source file cannot be saved (see below):

```
str()
and received error in str. default(): argument "object" is missing with no default
```

Comment: Based on the error message in your first paragraph: try saving the active document before changing the working directory. The _second_ paragraph is showing something seeming unrelated: it isn’t quite clear what you’re actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

you set working directory using `setwd()` not `str()`.

and if you are using RStudio, here is also a script to add at the beginning of your file to immediately set the current working directory to where the file is located.

```
library(rstudioapi)

setwd(dirname(getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
```

Comment: It might be obvious to some but just to make it explicit: this code *only* works in RStudio, and even there *only* if executed from within a document (it won’t work for instance if executed from a background job or from the built-in terminal).

Comment: @KonradRudolph ahhh thanks I'll improve the answer based on your comment. I've been using RStudio so I forgot I just took that for granted.